# InvalidArgumentException Route [account-activate] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

This is my route.php and I have also given the link of activate account. Then also "InvalidArgumentException 
Route [account-activate] not defined." this error is coming:

```
<?php
Route::get('/',array(
    'as'=>'home',
    'uses'=>'HomeController@home'
));

//unauthenticated grp
Route::group(array('before'=>'guest'), function() {

    //cross side request forgery protection

    Route::group(array('before'=>'csrf'), function() {

        //create acc(POST)
        Route::post('/account/create',array(
            'as'=>'account-create-post',
            'uses'=>'AccountController@postCreate'
        ));

    });

    //create acc(GET)
    Route::get('/account/create',array(
        'as'=>'account-create',
        'uses'=>'AccountController@getCreate'
    ));

});
```

Comment: post your routes file.

Comment: I have posted my route.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a route to your routes.php file (located under app/) to define the 'account-activate' route that you are using to create the link in your e-mail.

If the function that will process the request is in the AccountController and it is called getAccountActivate then the route declaration will look like:

```
Route::get('/whateverUrlYouWant', [
          'as' => 'account-activate',
          'uses' => 'AccountController@getAccountActivate',
          ]);
```

You can use any URL, Controller and function. Put the URL you want to be associated with that route.